# Error overloading () operator in a C++ template class

Tags: templates, visual-c++, operator-overloading

While creating a Matrix class for easy multidimensional access to an array, i stumbled upon a weird error: If creating more than one overload for the () operator, the Visual Studio C++ optimizer (2010 and 2012) crashes.

I managed to isolate the error. Putting this as the single code file in a project will make it crash:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
    T& Foo::operator() (int i)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // C1001 - Commenting this second overload makes the compiler work correctly
    T& Foo::operator() (char c)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

The original code had an overload with (int x, int y), and another with (Vector2 pos), but the error is the same.

Is there a workaround for this, or is it a VS bug I'll have to live with?

Comment: Could be because the types are effectively treated as the same? Since a `char` is promoted to an `int` before being passed to the function

Comment: Try changing the signature of one of them with (int i, int j). The same thing happens

Comment: @Osguima3 Consider tagging your question as answered if your problem is solved ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not allowed to use `Foo::` inside your class scope when it is as a *declarator-id*. Try this :

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
    T& operator() (int i)
    // ^
    {
        return 0;
    }

    T& operator() (char c)
    // ^
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Also, returning `0` will not compile as you are trying to return a `reference`.

And finally, the operators are `private` in your example ;)

Comment: It is "correct" to use `Foo::` inside the class' definition (it's the injected-class-name), but it's not allowed in a *declarator-id* (like any other qualification) if the referred name hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: Wouldn't the return 0 be the same as return NULL? Anyway, this was just the isolated code, of course it makes no sense to have private operators ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's your illegal use of `Foo::`. Remove this, and the code compiles. It looks like VC++ knows it isn't valid, but cannot report a compilation error.

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
    T& operator() (int i)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    T& operator() (char c)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};
```